# SQL Server query to get back comma separated string rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

if I have a column like so that has string separated values.

If a user passes in 22b OR 24 from a program, how can I bring back rows 2-4?

I tried wild card and "LIKE" with no luck

```
some_column
-------
21a
22b
21a, 22b, 24, 25
21a, 22b, 24, 25
```

Comment: Protip: normalization, otherwise you will end up with some ugly split function:)

Comment: As @lad2025 suggests, it really would be a better idea to normalize your data - create a table with a single value rather than a comma-list.

Comment: I would prefer not to...if all else fails then we will do that

Comment: so the & is interpreted as "OR"? Otherwise it would be only lines 3 and 4 sind 2 has only 22b but not 24...

Comment: @Tyron78 yes sorry...

Comment: It's better to fix your schema sooner than later.  Otherwise, you'll have a miserable time with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive cte for the splitting... depending on the amount of data this might become pretty painful! anyways, following an example:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
 x NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('21a'), ('22b'), ('21a, 22b, 24, 25'), ('21a, 22b, 24, 25');


WITH cte AS(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS rn
        ,X
    FROM @t t
),
cteRec AS(
    SELECT  rn,
            1 lvl,
            x AS OrigCol,
            x AS SplitCol
      FROM cte
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  rn,
            lvl+1 AS lvl,
            SUBSTRING(OrigCol, CHARINDEX(',', OrigCol)+1, LEN(OrigCol) - CHARINDEX(',', OrigCol)),
            SUBSTRING(OrigCol, 1, CHARINDEX(',', OrigCol)-1)
      FROM cteRec
      WHERE CHARINDEX(',', OrigCol) > 0
),
cteFilter AS(
  SELECT rn, REPLACE(SplitCol, ' ', '') SplitCol
    FROM cteRec
    WHERE CHARINDEX(',', SplitCol) = 0
)
SELECT DISTINCT     c.rn,
                    c.x
  FROM cte AS c
  JOIN cteFilter AS f ON c.rn = f.rn
  WHERE f.SplitCol = '24' OR f.SplitCol = '22b'
  order by rn
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: if you're on SQL 2016 or newer, with a 130 or greater compatibility level, you can use the STRING_SPLIT() function that's now built into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow why your LIKE didn't work. This code returns rows 2 through 4 for me...

```
create table #test (some_column varchar(20));

insert  #test values ('21a'), ('22b'), ('21a, 22b, 24, 25'), ('21a, 22b, 24, 25');

select *
from    #test
where   some_column like '%22b%'
        or some_column like '%24%';
```

...

```
some_column
--------------------
22b
21a, 22b, 24, 25
21a, 22b, 24, 25

(3 rows affected)
```